# How do I create an external link in the navigation? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, external, nav

### The website : http://www.viktor.ronnow.org/

I'm actually using a template for my website that has a hidden navbar that only appears when hovering on the "show-menu" button.

For some reason, when I try to add an external link inside the nav (that should normally lead to my other tumblr blog), the loader start spinning but doesn't redirect to the tumblr.

I don't know if it's because the link is external or there's something inside the javascript.

Here's my code:

```
<nav>
<ul>

    <li id="menu-item-80" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80">
        <a href="../about/">VIKTOR RØNNOW</a>
    </li>

    <li id="menu-item-92" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-92">
        <a href="http://www.viktor.ronnow.org">PROJECTS</a>
    </li>

    <!-- The PROBLEM -->
    <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78">
        <a href="http://www.viktorronnow.tumblr.com">JOURNAL</a>
    </li>
    <!-- /The PROBLEM -->

    <li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79">
        <a href="../contact/">CONTACT</a>
    </li>

</ul>
</nav>
```

### Feel free to go inside the code of my page

All the files :

### http://www.mediafire.com/download/2pn2a0rhrh0sy29/viktorronnow-website.zip

Comment: Check your dev console - F12 - this is related to CORS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: The thing is that i'm a beginner and this seems a bit advanced. Could you please explain me ? Thanks! :)

Comment: It's a set of specs that allow websites to prevent you from accessing resources they don't want you to access. It's implemented in new browsers to work with those websites to prevent wrongful use of resources.

Answer (score 0):

In the all.min.js, all nav link clicks are prevented from their default behaviour and they are using a prototype class Ajax call to obtain their data into a single main division.

When you put an external link, it tries to fetch this link via Ajax and fails due to the lack of [cross-origin permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

I got to resolve this by adding a function that checks if the href is a url using a regular expression, if so it uses `window.location` to redirect the page, other wise the default ajax request will be called.

In your all.min.js file, replace lines 1616-1633 which is the `Cass.prototype.goToPage` function definition with the following code :

```
function isUrl(s) {
   var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
   return regexp.test(s);
}

Cass.prototype.goToPage = function(url) {

 //console.log(isUrl(url));

  if(isUrl(url))
  {
     window.location = url;

  }
  else
  {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
          var $data, newClasses, response;
          response = cass.preprocessAjaxResponse(data);
          $data = response.data.find('.wrapper');
          newClasses = response.classes;
          cass.wrapper.attr('class', newClasses);
          cass.main.html($data.find('main').html());
          cass.main.find('.overlay').hide();
          cass.init();
          cass.loader.delay(500).fadeOut(500);
        }
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much !

Comment: You're welcome. @ViktorRønnow can you please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the template you are using assumes that all the links you put into your navigation are part of this same site, so external links aren't supported. When you click on a link, the page basically sends an ajax request to get the content of the new page and shows it to the user and update the URL (search all.min.js for cass.goToPage). To have it open up external links the normal way, insert this one simple line on line 1683 of all.min.js (right after cass.navLinks.on('click', function(e) {)

```
if($(this).attr('href').split('/')[2] != window.location.host) return;
```

Basically what this does is tell the browser to open the link in the expected way if the domain is different from the current domain, ie an external link.

Comment: This resolves it but it prohibits other functionality in the binded event that is needed by the function, besides what if another links (other than navlinks) in the template are using the same goToPage function, in this way you will need to add your code everywhere that is overriding the default link behavior which is wrong.

Comment: There is no other functionality in the binded event that is needed because the browser leaves the page

Comment: But still you have to add the same code whenever goToPage is called out of the scope you added it.

Comment: There is no other time when goToPage is called where it is necessary to check if the link is external

Comment: How can you make sure?? What if for any reason new links were added and used the native behavior, this would then be a mess, besides line 1779 is using the same function. It's better to solve it from within to prevent redundancy and decrease the troubleshooting scope.

Comment: You can "be sure" by searching the source code. If new links were added that used the "native behavior" of a link, then this wouldn't be an issue at all.